# Should I use laravel/ui to integrate ReactJs into a Laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, laravel-ui

Is there **benefits or downsides** to using `composer require laravel/ui` for scaffolding a **Laravel with ReactJs project** instead of installing ReactJs with `npm` manually and editing `webpack.mix.js`

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.jsx', 'public/js')
   .react();
```

Is there a conventional/better way to bring **ReactJS** to **Laravel**?

---

1. Am I likely to miss a setting if I do not use laravel/ui
2. Will I be enforced to follow some absurd rules if I use laravel/ui
3. Does laravel/ui really makes the setup easier.

...

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto check my edit. I never used ReactJS before and I won't be comfortable integrating it in a project without knowing that I did it in a correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quote from [laravel/ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui) repo the following

> **This legacy package** is a very simple authentication scaffolding built on the Bootstrap CSS framework. While it continues to work with the latest version of Laravel, **you should consider using Laravel Breeze** for new projects. Or, for something more robust, consider Laravel Jetstream.

You can see that the project maintainers recommend in a direct way using another packages.

You should also take in count that the discussed scaffolding uses Bootstrap by default.

Finally, I don't see any shortcut in running `composer require laravel/ui && php artisan ui react` instead of
`npm install && --save-dev react react-dom` and adding `.react()` to webpack.mix

Comment: Thank you so much for the quote. Also I prefer Tailwind over Bootstrap which will highly encourages me to avoid laravel/ui if it enforces using it or requires alot of tweaking to replace it with tailwind

Comment: The word **legacy** is enough to kill it for me. But you can visit the repo and see Bootstrap all around the project. I see Mix as the futur of bringing FrontEnd JS to Laravel projects